# Eclipse error log shows Crashlytics ran into an issue determining updating the kits for a project

Tags: android, eclipse, crashlytics

**Stack trace:**

```
com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.library.AndroidLibraryGraphFactory$DependencyException: Crashlytics found 1 unresolved dependencies.
Crashlytics found 1 unresolved dependencies.
com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.library.AndroidLibraryGraphFactory$DependencyException: Crashlytics found 1 unresolved dependencies.
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.library.AndroidLibraryGraphFactory.getLibraries(AndroidLibraryGraphFactory.java:211)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.eclipse.library.IvyKitUpdater$KitUpdateBehavior.call(IvyKitUpdater.java:67)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.eclipse.library.IvyKitUpdater$KitUpdateBehavior.call(IvyKitUpdater.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```